# I want to embed a bunch of third party social bs without errors

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, same-origin-policy

I'm using plugins and embeds to pull MY content from other places as well as AJAX to pull from my own DB. It mostly works but I'm getting 100+ errors each page load (Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL), same origin policy stuff.

The markup for Google Maps is:

```
<a class="various iframe" href="http://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ADDRESSINFO&amp;output=embed">
    <img src="map.png" alt="gmaps" width="100"/>
</a>
```

YouTube:

```
<a class='various iframe' href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOCODE' rel='venue-photos'>
    <img src="videothumb.png" alt="gmaps" width="100"/>
</a>
```

I'm also connecting to Facebook and Twitter.

I have or can get keys & API tokens.

Short error:
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"

Long error:
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "MYURL" from frame with URL "Twitter URL". The frame requesting access set 'document.domain' to 'twitter.com', but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access."

Any advice on changing the document.domain is appreciated, I'm not really sure how to switch back and forth or trigger change just when it's getting the data? And also how it effects my own AJAX origin.

What codes are you using for social plugins? They seem to constantly be changing and I often need slightly different snippets to work with gallery plugins etc. so I kind of mix what they say and what the plugin developer says.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to access javascript in a frame from your main page (or vice versa). You cannot do that if they point to different domains (e.g. your domain vs. twitter.com) You can however embed them freely. I.e. the frame can contain whatever you want, just don't call functions in that frame from your frame (or vice versa).

The only property in the loaded frame you should / could access would be the parent's location property. `parent.location`

Comment: Interesting, it must be the plugin trying to do something. I thought it was possible if you pass a token that links to your youtube account for example, then you'd be able access more functions?